# Show a div after 3 minutes from page load

Tags: javascript

The disclaimer div needs to appear 3 minutes after the page loads, the disappear when the user click on the a tag

Currently have

```
<div id="disclaimer">
    <p>Text</p>
    <a OnClick="hidePopup()">
</div>
function hidePopup() {
    document.getElementById("disclaimer").style.display = "none";
    setTimeout(hidePopup, 3 * 60 * 1000);
}

function Popup() {
    document.getElementById("disclaimer").style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: How or where do you call Popup?

Answer (score 1):

What's the point of calling `hidePopup` after three minutes?

```
<div id="disclaimer" style="display:none">
    <p>Text</p>
    <a onClick="hidePopup()">hide</a>
</div>

function hidePopup() {
    document.getElementById("disclaimer").style.display = "none";
}
function showPopup() {
    document.getElementById("disclaimer").style.display = "block";
}
setTimeout(showPopup, 3 * 60 * 1000);
```